# flow of recursive calls explanation?

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonaci(int i)
{
   if(i == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }
   if(i == 1)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return fibonaci(i-1) + fibonaci(i-2);
}



int  main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       printf("%d\t", fibonaci(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that this *function* indicates a *binary tree*. Why is that so? I have browsed through all the relevant answers but they all failed to provide the appropriate explanation. Any help documents regarding recursion would be highly appreciated. If possible provide me some hyperlinks. I would be super helpful to me.

Comment: Why not step through with a debugger?

Comment: Sorry,my bad! Explanation is not necessary.Could you please tell me why it is referred to as a binary tree? I hope this question is fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

A function that calls itself is known as `recursive function` and the process of calling function itself is known as `recursion` in C programming. Here the `fibonaci(i)` is called `10` times.

the `fibonacci series` is like this:`1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34`

Starting with 0 and 1, each new number in the series is simply the sum of the two before it.

```
if(i == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }
   if(i == 1)
   {
      return 1;  //returns 1 if i=1
   }
   return fibonaci(i-1) + fibonaci(i-2);  // if it is 2 or greater than 2
```

In `mathematical terms`, the sequence Fn of Fibonacci numbers is defined by the recurrence relation

```
  F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}
```

with seed values

```
 F_0 = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad F_1 = 1.
```

Write a function int fib(int n) that returns F_n. For example, if n = 0, then fib() should return 0. If n = 1, then it should return 1. For n > 1, it should return  `F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}`

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me why it is referred to as a binary tree?

The function execution sequence in a program can be depicted as a tree, e. g.

```
program()
{
    input(x);
    proc(x);
    output(x);
}
```

corresponds to the tree

```
         program()
        /    |    \ 
input(x)  proc(x)  output(x)
```

of size (number of nodes) 4 and height 1 (assuming input, proc and output are leaf functions).

Now, if a function as well as every function called from it executes at most two function calls (as is the case with your `fibonaci()`), the corresponding graph is a binary tree because every node has at most two children. Example for the tree starting with the call `fibonaci(5)`, then abbreviated `f`:

```
                   fibonaci(5)
                 /             \
            f(4)                 f(3)
           /    \                /  \
      f(3)        f(2)        f(2)  f(1)
      /  \        /  \        /  \
   f(2)  f(1)  f(1)  f(0)  f(1)  f(0)
   /  \
f(1)  f(0)
```